# Workaround for Unity AnimatorController not able to be created at runtime?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, animator

We have a Unity project targeting Android wherein we need to create and modify AnimatorControllers at runtime.

I'm aware that **AnimatorController is part of the UnityEditor class (therefore it cannot be accessed when built to Android)** and that there is a separate RuntimeAnimatorController that can be extracted as a reference to AnimatorControllers that were already created prior to runtime. The problem is that RuntimeAnimatorControllers cannot be created or used to modify properties like triggers or layers, so this is not a solution.

Is there any known workaround or separate package that would allow us to create and modify AnimatorControllers at runtime in Unity when built to Android?